# MySQL: Source Error 2? No File Found

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, netbeans

When I tried to source for a particular .sql file, namely `'registrar.sql'`, the following error is displayed:

```
Failed to open file 'registrar.sql', error: 2
```

I know that this means the below error:

```
#define ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
```

However, I am not sure how to be more specific as I have tried entering 'source registrar.sql' and I have tried entering the absolute path.  Now it is possible I am just entering the absolute path incorrect which is where I could use some help.  Here is the path in properties in windows.

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin`

File name is: `registrar.sql`

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
mysql> source c:/dumps/mydatabase.sql
```

That is, use forward slash instead of back slash

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart mysql if you have copied file after starting mysql server.

also if you have space in file or folder name you should use **quotes**.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm not sure we really need to restart mysql after importing an sql dump file...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier we are not, but sometimes mysql cache old data. This is not actual solution but few times I solved same problem like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the sql process might not have read access to your directory anyway. In which case, you might have to copy the sql file to other accessible folder and tell mysql the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces in the folder names of the path, It worked for my mac path.

> (Eg: change the folder name MySQL Server 5.1 to MySQLServer5.1)